# Конструкция кажется слишком перегруженной. Как лучше упростить?

Tags: python

```
    interns = [
              (lambda x: (-int(x[1]), int(x[2]), x[0]))
              (input().split()) for _ in range(number)
    ]
```

Формат ввода
В первой строке задано число участников n, 1 ≤ n ≤ 100 000.
В каждой из следующих n строк задана информация про одного из участников.
i-й участник описывается тремя параметрами:

уникальным логином (строкой из маленьких латинских букв длиной не более 20)
числом решённых задач Pi
штрафом Fi
Fi и Pi — целые числа, лежащие в диапазоне от 0 до 109.
Формат вывода
Для отсортированного списка участников выведите по порядку их логины по одному в строке.

Пример 1
Ввод

> ```
> 5
> alla 4 100
> gena 6 1000
> gosha 2 90
> rita 2 90
> timofey 4 80
> ```

Вывод:

> ```
> gena
> timofey
> alla
> gosha
> rita
> ```

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, ввод-вывод.

Comment: не пойму как нормально код в комментарий вставить )

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос, удалите комментарий

Comment: В комментарий вставить также - ` в начале и в конце кода

Comment: @Anton, неверно. Это применимо для одной строки, а не для кода.

Comment: Андрей, редактируйте вопросы, не надо в комментариях важную информацию по вопросу  писать. Я перенес сейчас сам уже.

Comment: извиняюсь, ещё толком не знаю что тут и как )

Comment: это часть рабочего кода. В таком виде всё работает, но мне сказали что нужно упростить эту часть, чтобы читалось лучше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте функцию для чтения:

```
def input_record():
    t0, t1, t2 = input().split()
    return -int(t1), int(t2), t0


interns = [input_record() for _ in range(number)]
```

Comment: я делал изначально через отдельную функцию, потом решил меньше строк сделать. Но, конечно, у меня это было не так элегантно. Спасибо!